# How to instantiate org.opengis.geometry.Geometry?

Tags: java, geotools

I am trying to create a `org.opengis.filter.Filter` to find features within a certain geometry. The code to create this factory is:

```
public static Filter createPartiallyContainedFilter(final Geometry area) {
    return CommonFactoryFinder.getFilterFactory2(GeoTools.getDefaultHints()).dwithin(
        "geometry", area, 40, "centimeter");
}
```

The problem I have is that I can't figure out how to create a geometry object. The method to create the filter expects a geometry object of type `org.opengis.geometry.Geometry`, which is an interface.

I'd tried to create an instance as follows:

```
GeometryFactory factory = GeometryFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory(org.geotools.factory.GeoTools
    .getDefaultHints());
factory.createPolygon(...);
```

However, this will result into an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.geotools.factory.FactoryNotFoundException: No factory of kind "GeometryFactory" found.
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.getServiceProvider(FactoryRegistry.java:375)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryCreator.getServiceProvider(FactoryCreator.java:145)
    at org.geotools.geometry.GeometryFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory(GeometryFactoryFinder.java:94)
    at nl.kadaster.locatie.bis.wfs.pdok.PdokServiceMain.main(PdokServiceMain.java:28)
```

Can anyone tell me how to create a geometry object instance?

Sincerely,
Stefan

Comment: `dwithin()` returns a `DWithin` not a `Filter`. Does your code compile?

Comment: Maybe the code in this question helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404090/converting-lat-long-to-jts

Comment: are you using maven to pull in your dependencies? The error looks like an SPI/Jar issue